# How to use a .JAR file class in my project (Eclipse)

Tags: java, libraries

I am trying to use a class from org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;

I have alread imported the .JAR file into my classpath in ecplise. You can see in the picture below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cg2YJ.png  [<**image here**]

When I hover over the error for ArrayUtils.indexOf (circle in blue). It gives me no option to import class for ArrayUtils.

This is a photo of the .JAR: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WN7pw.png

I cannot figure out how to use ArrayUtils in my code without an error.

I am still learning Java any help will be appreciated, I have looked at a similar question already: [how do I import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils; into Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30555847/how-do-i-import-org-apache-commons-lang3-arrayutils-into-eclipse)

and it did not help me specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, import on the top

import `org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils`;

shortcut key to import in eclipse is `ctrl+space`

Comment: Man I feel dumb, but thank you very much for your answer, it solved my issue.

Comment: @proggerfr sometime its was happened but it's okay  :p